# c++: how to add an environmental variable only for the current process?

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls

Basically the question is in the title. I'm using the `setenv()` fucntion to set the environmental variable in my cpp program, where I also use `fork()` `exec()` chain, which create a child process. The problem is that the created variable is also accessible from this child process. This makes `setenv()` equivalent to `export ABC=EFG` behavior in the shell. What I want is to separate this functionality. I want to separately set the variable `ABC=EFG` and make it available to the child process `export ABC`. How to do this?

**EDIT:** I decided to add my comment to @SergeyA's answer here. How does bash handle env variables in a situation like this, for example? If I write ABC=EFG and call a script consisting from only one line echo $ABC it won't print anything unless I previously called export ABC. I'm just writing a shell and trying to mimic this behavior.

Comment: @Frank Added, thanks for the remark.

Comment: There's a distinction between normal shell variables and environment variables. Shells only provide the latter to processes they execute, via one of the `exec*()` functions that takes an environment argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing this. Calling `exec` is always going to make child process inheriting environment variables of the parent process.

You can use `exceve` to explicitly specify environment variables to be visible to child process.

Comment: But how does bash handle env variables in a situation like this, for example? If I write `ABC=EFG` and call a script consisting from only one line `echo $ABC` it won't print anything unless I previously called `export ABC`. I'm just writing a shell and trying to mimic this behavior

Comment: @sauce I have not seen it's source code, but I'd imagine, it uses similar technique.